# Counter example for continuity and limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Can someone please show me one example of a continuous function: $f : X\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \neq f(a)$ with $a \in X$?

The converse is clear for me, that means if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} = f(a)$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

I was trying to look for some definition of $f$ where we'd have $a \in X' \setminus X$...

I'd appreciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused - if a function $f$ is continuous at a point, then doesn't $f(a) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$?

Comment: @paulinho That is valid iff $a \in X \cap X'$.

Comment: @BrunoReis what is $X'$?

Comment: @ArsenBerk $X'$ is the set of accumulation points of the domain of our function.

Comment: Then how would you define $f(a)$ for $X'\setminus X$? You only define it on $X$ in your question

Comment: @BrunoReis No, that must be valid for any $\;x\in X\;$ if $\;f\;$ is continous on $\;X\;$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree, but what if $J = X' \setminus X \neq \emptyset$ and we take a limit to a point $a \in J$ ? In that case, we don't have $a \in X$, but we have $a \in X'$, so we can talk about the limit. Is there a continuous function with a limit in a point in $J$ s.t that limit is not $f(a)$? It wouldn't be $f(a)$ because $a \notin X$... Makes sense?

Comment: @BrunoReis Read my answer...and yes, we can talk of **the limit** at some $\;t\in J\;$ , but we can *not* talk of $\;f(t)\;$ since $\;t\;$ is not in the domain of definition of $\;f\;$ ...! Menaing: the question about continuity of $\;f\;$ at some point $\;t\;$ **not in its domain of definition** is completely moot.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusing things here: it $\;f:X\to\Bbb R\;$ is continuous, then for **any** $\;a\in X\;$ it must be true that

$$\lim_{x\to a\\x\in X}f(x)=f(a)\;$$

This is just part of definition (or of what follows from it, depending on your particular definition of continuity).

The above has nothing to do with the fact that if $\;\{x_n\}\subset X\;$ , then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=x\in X\iff x\in X'\;$ , which is perhaps what you're thinking of.

Comment: It makes sense... I'm thinking about that because that was a question in a test, to find that counterexample... So I was thinking that what was written on a test was true, and it seems that it's not.

Comment: Most probably the wording of the question was different and they meant something else, or perhaps that was a mistake. It occurs all the time...

Comment: Thank you anyway @DonAntonio. Now what if $X = (a,b) \cup \{c\}$ where $c \notin (a,b)$ ? Then we can't talk about limit in $c$ since $c \notin X'$...

Comment: Well, if we require $\;x\to a\,,\,\,x\in X\;$ then yes: that cannot be. What is important here is that **everything** must happen within $\;X\;$ , which is the definition domain of $\;f\;$ .

Comment: When you mean everything, you mean that necessarily $ a \in X$?

Comment: @BrunoReis Of course! We cannot have $\;a\notin X\;$ as $\;f\;$ is defined **only** on $\;X\;$ ...we cannot tell anything about $\;f\;$ ouside its given domain of definition!

Comment: @DonAntonio not quite true: e.g. for the function $f(x)=x$ on $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ we can certainly talk about $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ and say the limit is $0$ even though $f$ is not defined at $0$...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't mean that, of course. I meant the use of $\;f(a)\;$ for $\;a\notin X\;$ . This doesn't mean anything within this context..!

Comment: We *can* have $a \notin X$, that's my point.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Very nice that's your point: it wasn't the OP's and neither mine's, as the OP clearly write $\;f(a)\;$ for some $\;a\in X\;$ and then $\;\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq f(a)\;$ , which cannot be as the function's continuous **at the point** $\;a\in X\;$ ... This is what I and others tried to explain to him.

Answer (score 1):

If $f: X=(0,1) \cup \{2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=\sin(\frac1x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(2)=42$ then $f$ is continuous on $X$ (continuity is trivial on isolated points: take $\delta=1$ for any $\epsilon>0$, e.g.) but $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$ does not exist as $2 \notin X'$ (but $2 \in X$); and as a bonus $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist even though we *do* have $0 \in X'$.

Or take any function defined on $X=\mathbb{Z}$. No limit exists to points of $X$ (or outside) as $X'=\emptyset$.

Comment: This is not what was asked. For the examples to be relevant you should have $\;f(1),\,f(0)\;$ or something of the like...which you cannot as you defined your function **not on those points** .

Comment: @DonAntonio No, $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$ does not exist (so is not equal to $f(2)$), even though $2 \in X$, so it's a valid example.

Comment: No, it's not since there's an open neighborhood of $\;a=2\;$ in which the function isn't even *defined* ...you cannot take the limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to 2}f(x)\;$ ! This is the main point (with a twist) that I tried to explain the OP...

Comment: @DonAntonio Exactly, that's why the limit is not equal to $f(2)$: it does not exist.. We seem to agree and not agree at the same time.

Comment: I try to abide by the very basic definitions of these very basic things. For me to be **even able to talk** about $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\;$ , the function $\;f\;$ **must** be defined in some open neighborhood of $\;a\;$, otherwise the whole thing is meaningless...

Comment: @DonAntonio $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=p$ is a *combined* statement "$\phi_1 \land \phi_2$, where $\phi_1$ says that $a \in X'$ (so that every punctured neighbourhood of $a$ has values of the domain: it need not be an interior point) and $\phi_2$ asserts the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition wrt $p$. So saying he limit is **not** $p$ (so asserting $\lnot (\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=p)$ (!)) can be done by negating clause $\phi_1$ or clause $\phi_2$, and if $\phi_1$ is fulfilled and $a \in X$ and $f$ is continuous we cannot deny $\phi_2$ anymore, so we must negate $\phi_1$ and "kill" the limit that way.